# Is it possible to upload file to s3 bucket directly without redirect?

Tags: amazon-s3

I am trying to upload a file to S3 bucket directly from browser. Actually it works the only thing is bothering me that it needs a redirect after uploading. I removed redirect option from policy and form. It works but it returns 204 HTTP status, so I don't get response from the server and can't react. Have I other way to get response without redirect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to the documentation http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectPOST.html

success_action_redirect, redirect is an optional param and if success_action_redirect is not specified, Amazon S3 returns the empty document type specified in the success_action_status field